# GraphQL dataloader with Firebase Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, graphql, graphql-js

I'm using for this project Firebase Firestore, and I'm trying to implement dataloaders to reduce request to the server.

In this particular case, I have a Category collection structured like this:
(I'll use typescript to better define my code)

```js
type Category = {
    name: String
    parent?: Category
}
```

when I query the graphql endpoint, in resolvers I verify if the category has a parent, and if one is present, I query the database for details. Here's come the dataloader.

This is my Dataloader implementation for Firestore:

```js
 private dataLoader = new DataLoader(async (ids: readonly string[]) => {
    // firestore limits batches to 10
    let batches: Category[] = [];
    const tmp = [...ids];
    while (tmp.length) {
        const batch = tmp.splice(0, 10);
        const result = await this.collection.where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', [...batch]).get();
        batches = [...batches, ...result.docs.map(d => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() } as Category))];
    }

    return batches;
});
```

the resolver itself calls this method

```js
public async getById(id: string): Promise<Category> {
    const foo = await this.dataLoader.load(id);
    console.log('required', id, 'received', foo.id);
    return foo;
}
```

but as you can see in this sample output, it messes up big time:

```
required ztdOcVv9JdNp6U54ySed received 4jXbScd1qTwPStXocaoc
required Qnb86GsOy0gSgGxmMqYR received NeuCCRrJyurQTxvlAVhs
required NeuCCRrJyurQTxvlAVhs received Qnb86GsOy0gSgGxmMqYR
required 4jXbScd1qTwPStXocaoc received ztdOcVv9JdNp6U54ySed
```

My understanding is that somewhere async cause some trouble, but no idea where or how to solve this. That's why I'm here asking for help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: These look like the auto-generated ID strings from the Firestore. When you add a new document to a collection, Firestore automatically generates the document identifier. Check in the Firebase Firestore console to check.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your comment and sorry for the delay. They are the auto generated ids actually. And they're present in the database. Just not the ones I need. They do not match and what I dont understand is how this output is generated. It has no sense at all

Comment: Can you add a copy of the database structure to your question? What are you expecting to see instead? You mention that it messes up but I am not sure how from your description.

Comment: Andrew, as you may infer from the type code, is just a field, name, and an optional field called parent, which is, when present, a document reference to another category in the same collection. In the dataloader, I pass a batch of ids (in group of ten, because of the limitations imposed by Firebase itself) and it should return the relative items. Instedad, it return "shuffled result", as you may see on the sample output.

Comment: Well, reading through this I'd like to point out that you've not ordered the result, and you're looking at any results that are contained in your batches... So really the order you're getting isn't "shuffled", it's the order in which it was saved in Firestore. Which, looking at the first character, is alphabetical, which means it's sorted by char value (4<N<Q< Z). You could add a timestamp to the category to see when you add it and fetch it by that index. Also, I'm afraid I must concur with Andrew in asking the structure. To infer is to assume, and we know what assuming makes out of you and me

Comment: @fabc thanks for your answer. I've in the end excluded the dataloader but I'm planning an update on that code soon. I'll try your suggestion and let you know if it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to return a loop of the `ids` in the DataLoader function, mapping the fetched objects (categories in this case) to the corresponding id.

Here is how I implemented something similiar:

```
async function getItemsByIds(ids: string[]) {
  // where in supports max 10 values
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries
  const chunks = _.chunk(ids, 10);
  const snapshots = await Promise.all(
    chunks.map((chunk) =>
      admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('items')
        .where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', chunk)
        .get()
    )
  );
  return snapshots.flatMap((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }));
  });
}

const itemDataLoader = new DataLoader(async (ids) => {
  const items = await getItemsByIds(ids);
  return ids.map((id) => {
    const item = items.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (!item) {
      return new Error('Item not found');
    }
    return item;
  });
})
```

Note: I used lodash to help with the chunking of 10 items per request and unnesting the chunked arrays.

Comment: I'd just return `null` instead of using `new Error("item not found")` as the stack trace wouldn't be useful and will just add bloat to the response. I'd also consider building a map of ids -> data rather than calling find on the array repeatedly in a loop. While the code does look simple here, performance takes a hit.

Comment: Using find was the culprit. Now result are coherent! But now I'm interested in how @samthecodingman would implement the dataloader. It is actually true that find has that impact in performance?

Comment: @samthecodingman is not wrong, but like everything it depends. If you pass thousands of ids to the dataloader, you should probably not use a `find` for every record. 

Another thing; I just had a look at the [DataLoader docs](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader#new-dataloaderbatchloadfn--options), and noticed they have a `maxBatchSize` option. This could probably remove the need for lodash chunking/flatmapping.

Comment: Following up on @jonespen's point, if you make use of `maxBatchSize` you won't run into this problem. But if you want to explore the difference in performance, I've thrown together a [JSBench](https://jsbench.me/cqkp459ox4/1) for it using generated data. By changing the first line of the setup section, you could test any number of IDs.